# Javascript append child nest

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create several of these:

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="observation">Observation</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <textarea class="form-control" id="paragraphx" name="whatever" placeholder="test">
    test</textarea>
        </div>
 </div>
```

using the javascript below:

```
function addParagraph()
{
     var div1=document.createElement('div');
     var div2=document.createElement('div');
     var label=document.createElement('label');
     var text=document.createElement('textarea');

     div1.setAttribute('class','form-group');
     div2.setAttribute('class','col-sm-10');

     label.setAttribute('class','col-sm-2 control-label');
     label.setAttribute('for','paragraph');
     label.setAttribute('id','paragraph'+p);

     text.setAttribute('class','form-control');
     text.setAttribute('id','paragraph');
     text.setAttribute('name','item'+i);
     text.setAttribute('placeholder','Add another paragraph here.');

     div2.appendChild(text);
     label.appendChild(div2);
     div1.appendChild(label);

     document.getElementById('myForm').appendChild(div1);
     document.getElementById("paragraph"+p).innerHTML = "Paragraph";
     increment();
}
```

However, this is the only thing that's getting rendered in HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label id="paragraph1" for="xxxxxx" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Paragraph
   </label>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong? Shouldn't label be adding div2 as its child? Or did I use AppendChild the wrong way?

*****EDIT*****

Thanks so much for the input, guys. The only issue I have now is trying to get the placeholder to actually load after it loads the textbox. For example, right now it only shows the placeholder after I click in the textbox.

Comment: where is `myForm`? are you sure it exists?

Comment: Positive. It's on a page that's calling the script. I just didn't include it in the example. It's successfully adding a div class and label to the form, but not the other 2 childs (div2 and text)

Comment: Why not just use a string of HTML, create the one parent object and set it's `.innerHTML`?

Comment: I'm not too experienced with Javascript, so I just went with the first thing that made sense to me. Is this a way to make it work with what I have, or just more convenient/efficient?

Comment: Better use properties instead of attributes when possible: `text.className = 'form-control'`, `text.id = 'paragraph'`, `text.name = 'item'+i`, `text.placeholder = 'Add another paragraph here.'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with this line

```
   document.getElementById("paragraph"+p).innerHTML = "Paragraph";
```

You are destroying the html content of your label element. Try to comment it and you will see what you get !

Also, I noticed these line

```
 div2.appendChild(text);
 label.appendChild(div2);
 div1.appendChild(label);
```

Will produce this output

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label id="paragraph1" for="xxxxxx" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
      <div><textarea></textarea></div>
   </label>
</div>
```

I think what you are trying to do is

```
 div2.appendChild(text);
 div1.appendChild(div2);
 div1.appendChild(label);
```

That would produce your expected output.

Comment: Wow. That worked. Is there any easier way to set the label to "Paragraph" then? Thanks so much for your help thus far.

Comment: Also - setting the same `id` on all the `textarea` elements (`text.setAttribute('id','paragraph');`) could lead to problems later.

Comment: Thanks. Going to make this change now :)

Comment: Instead of innerHtml, try to use textContent.

Comment: Thanks!!!! I've taken everyone's suggestions and I have things working now. The last problem I have is that the placeholder text doesn't show until I click in the text box. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: That would be another question :-)